# Looking for API path to retrieve user identities on Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure, server, tfs, devops

Using the TFS ExtendedClient Nuget package, we can extract identities using these actions:

```
    TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[DefaultCollection]\\Project Collection Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

    TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
```

This is the equivalent of sending this API call with different query params:
http://TFS/COLLECTION/_apis/identities?queryMembership=None

I'm trying to find the exact API calls with query params to achieve the same actions as in the Nuget package actions example.